# Adding multiple attributes to elements using Jade

Tags: pug

In Jade, `input(type='text' placeholder='Type in text')` yields a syntax error. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need a comma:

```
input(type='text', placeholder='Type in text')
```

https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/examples/attributes.jade

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 6):

You can use a comma.

```
input(type='text', placeholder='Type in text')
```

Or new line.

```
input(type='text'
      placeholder='Type in text')
```

See the documentation. https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#attributes